# Build dll and link to it?

Tags: dll, mingw, codeblocks, dynamic-linking

I'm on codeblocks 10.05 mingw on XP SP3 and I basically have the dll and the lib file built following [the mingw site on creating a dll and linking to it](http://www.mingw.org/wiki/sampleDLL). The problem I'm having is the second part where I'm trying to link to the library. I created a console application and used the following source:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include "example_dll.h"

int main(void)
{
    hello("World");
    printf("%d\n", Double(333));
    CppFunc();

    MyClass a;
    a.func();

    return 0;
}
```

Then I setup my linker settings just like the site says by adding `-L. -lexample_dll` and I also link with the library file libexample_dll.a just like I would with many other libraries that have worked successfully with the same settings. Then when I try to link the executable I get an error,

```
 C:\example_dll_client\example_dll_client.cpp|2|error: example_dll.h: No such file or directory|
C:\example_dll_client\example_dll_client.cpp||In function 'int main()':|
C:\example_dll_client\example_dll_client.cpp|6|error: 'hello' was not declared in this scope|
C:\example_dll_client\example_dll_client.cpp|7|error: 'Double' was not declared in this scope|
C:\example_dll_client\example_dll_client.cpp|8|error: 'CppFunc' was not declared in this scope|
C:\example_dll_client\example_dll_client.cpp|10|error: 'MyClass' was not declared in this scope|
C:\example_dll_client\example_dll_client.cpp|10|error: expected ';' before 'a'|
C:\example_dll_client\example_dll_client.cpp|11|error: 'a' was not declared in this scope|
||=== Build finished: 7 errors, 0 warnings ===|
```

I also included the two files used for building the dll and lib files (not to the project but to this site for reference. I only have the source with the error as the entire project, otherwise what would the point of the dll be?).

```cpp
//example_dll.cpp
#include <stdio.h>
#include "example_dll.h"

__stdcall void hello(const char *s)
{
        printf("Hello %s\n", s);
}
int Double(int x)
{
        return 2 * x;
}
void CppFunc(void)
{
        puts("CppFunc");
}
void MyClass::func(void)
{
        puts("MyClass.func()");
}
```

```cpp
//example_dll.h
#ifndef EXAMPLE_DLL_H
#define EXAMPLE_DLL_H

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#ifdef BUILDING_EXAMPLE_DLL
#define EXAMPLE_DLL __declspec(dllexport)
#else
#define EXAMPLE_DLL __declspec(dllimport)
#endif

void __stdcall EXAMPLE_DLL hello(const char *s);

int EXAMPLE_DLL Double(int x);

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

// NOTE: this function is not declared extern "C"
void EXAMPLE_DLL CppFunc(void);

// NOTE: this class must not be declared extern "C"
class EXAMPLE_DLL MyClass
{
public:
        MyClass() {};
        virtual ~MyClass() {};
        void func(void);
};

#endif  // EXAMPLE_DLL_H
```

EDIT:

I made the  following changes to the compilation of the DLL and lib file.

I first made sure that my build target is a dynamic library which can be found under the build targets tab by right clicking on the properties of the active project in the project manager tree. I also checked the create import library and the check .def exports file. I then went into the codeblocks build options and under the compiler settings->other-options tab I added

-c
-shared

and under the #defines tab I added

BUILDING_EXAMPLE_DLL
BUILD_DLL

My linker settings had user32 in the link libraries and under the linker settings I had 
-mwindows
--out-implib

The build should now compile and link with no errors or warnings.

For compiling the source with the int main() I included the header file and also these settings:

Under the link libraries I had libexample_dll.dll.a and under the linker settings I had

-L.
-lexample_dll

Comment: The first line of the error is a pretty good hint. Did you specify the include directory of where `example_dll.h` is located? (using the `-I` compiler switch).

Comment: Right, but isn't it supposed to be possible to compile my int main() code using nothing but the lib file? or how do I compiled the source with just the .DLL file?

Comment: Nevermind, the header file only contains the function calls etc. Nothing else. The cpp file contains the actual operations.

Comment: @lost_with_coding Have a look at my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To me it looks like you have different directories for exe and dll.

So `L.` is not OK. Should be `LpointsToThelibexample_dll.aFolder`.

Either to copying example_dll.h in your exe directory or you use `-IpointsToTheexample_dll.hFolder`.

To be sure, due to incorrect command, the execution does not work.
I made a makefile.

To test the makefile

- create a new directory.
- copy example_dll.h , example_dll.cpp , example_dll.cpp files in there.
- safe following code in the file makefile (in the same directory).

makefile

```
# Environment 
MKDIR=mkdir
CP=cp
CCADMIN=CCadmin


# build
builddll:
    g++ -c -DBUILDING_EXAMPLE_DLL example_dll.cpp
    g++ -shared -o example_dll.dll example_dll.o -Wl,--out-implib,libexample_dll.a

buildexe:
    g++ -c example_exe.cpp
    g++ -o example_exe.exe example_exe.o -L. -lexample_dll

clean:
    rm -f libexample_dll.a example_exe.exe example_dll.dll
```

**Because of a copy and paste error.**
Before you can use this makefile, replace all blank in front of the commands (g++ and rm) with two tabs.
Or you'll get an error like this. `makefile:9: *** missing separator.  Stop.`

execute the following command.

- make builddll
- make buildexe

Now you can test example_exe.exe

only because of the completeness there is also a make clean.

- make clean

**UPDATE**

If you want to use the DLL without headerfile, you have to know all the DLL functions.

Here's a loadDll.cpp that loads a DLL and calls `Double`.

```
/* 
 * File:   loadDll.cpp
 * Author: Administrator
 *
 * Created on 19. Februar 2013, 22:42
 */

#include <cstdlib>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

typedef int (WINAPI *PFNDOUBLE)(int x);
PFNDOUBLE idlldouble;
HINSTANCE dllctrl_inst;

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    puts("---start---");
    dllctrl_inst = LoadLibrary( "example_dll.dll" );
    if( dllctrl_inst != NULL ) {
      idlldouble = (PFNDOUBLE)GetProcAddress( dllctrl_inst, "Double" );
    }
    if( idlldouble != NULL ) {printf("%d\n", idlldouble(333));}
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: But isn't there some way to compile the source with the int main() with just the dll file also. The page mentions it, or do I need the example_dll.h file also? Microsofts api's are usually closed source and there are no header files except for windows.h but thats linked right?

Comment: Complete face palm! Check out my comment below my post. I was tired last night when I posted this and didn't realize the cpp file is not included in the int main() source and the .h file is which contains only the function calls etc. thanks for the help though.